# inject translator in my class .php

Tags: symfony, translation

How can call this function

```
 $this->get('translator')->trans()
```

in my class namespace Di\NotificationBundle\Manager;

```
class SMSManager
{ 
    private function send(){

      // call $this->get('translator')->trans()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your service and inject your parameter to that service. Then it's available in your constructor.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

and pass the translation service to your class as dependency as example:

```
  class SMSManager
  { 

public function __construct(
    TranslatorInterface $translator
) {
    $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

defined as example as:

```
acme_sms_manager:
    class: Di\NotificationBundle\Manager\SMSManager
    arguments:
        - '@translator'
```

then simply call as:

```
private function send(){

  this->translator->trans()
}
```

Hope this help